# Xamarin for Android using Azure Virtual Machine

Tags: c#, android, azure, xamarin

I'm trying to setup environment for Xamarin Android development on Azure VM.
Unfortunetelly I'm not able to configure hardware acceleration cause nested virtualization. Tried with HAXM and Hyper-V.

1. Anyone developed for Android with VM?
2. Is there any alternative for Android Emulator? (like accessing physical USB device from VM)